# How would I write this function in point-free style?

Tags: haskell

I'm just looking to make general improvements to my Haskell code, and was wondering if the following function could be made point-free? Mostly for curiosity's sake.

Given two functions which we'd like to use in our `filter`:

```
isZero = (==0)
isOne = (==1)
```

How would we go about utilising those two functions in our contrived example, but making it point-free?

```
filter (\x -> isZero x || isOne x) [0..100]
```

Comment: As instance, `filter ((||) <$> isZero <*> isOne) [0..100]`. Lift `(||)` to an Applicative functor like this: `(<||>) = liftA2 (||)`. And then use: `filter (isZero <||> isOne <||> ...) ...`

Comment: Note that `(||) <$> isZero <*> isOne` is 25 chars, and `\x -> isZero x || isOne x` is 25 chars. I'd stick with the pointful version, which is easier to read by humans.

Comment: @freestyle I love `<||>`. Hoping it's not use elsewhere with different meaning…

Comment: @Bergi It already defined in some packages, for example: control-bool, classy-prelude.

Comment: @chi I would also prefer pointful version.

Comment: @freestyle: I tend to spell `liftA2 (||)` as `.||.` because mnemonically there’s a “point” on both sides. If you’re really into APL-style tacit programming, you can add silly generalisations like `(..||..) = liftA2 (liftA2 (||))`, which allows things like `(>=) = (>) ..||.. (==)` (“‘greater than or equal to’ means ‘greater than’ or ‘equal to’”).

Answer (score 24):

There's a [online-service](http://pointfree.io/) for converting `Haskell` code to point-free.

It suggests: `filter (liftM2 (||) isZero isOne) [0..100]`

`liftA2 (||) isZero isOne` or `(||) <$> isZero <*> isOne` is also possible

`(||) <$> isZero` has type `a0 -> Bool -> Bool` and it's the composition of `(||)` and `isZero`. This composition takes a number (for `isZero`) and a boolean (as another argument for `(||)`)

So, it's the same as `\x y -> (||) (isZero x) y`

The function type is an instance of `Applicative Functor` and we can look at its implementation:

```
instance Applicative ((->) r) where  
    pure x = (\_ -> x)  
    f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)
```

So, `(||) <$> isZero <*> isOne` is the same as `\x -> ((||) <$> isZero) x (isOne x)` and the same as `\x -> (||) (isZero x) (isOne x)`

Thus, if there's `z x = y (f x) (g x)`, it can be transformed into point free: `z = y <$> f <*> g`

Comment: This doesn't explain how to scale this solution. I like @Rampion answer more because it explains how to use `liftA2 (||)` to write arbitrary number predications in point-free style.

Answer (score 7):

An alternate point-free form would be to use the `a -> Any` monoid:

```
λ import Data.Monoid (Any(..))
λ :t getAny . (Any . isZero <> Any . isOne)
getAny . (Any . isZero <> Any . isOne)
  :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> Bool
λ filter (getAny . (Any . isZero <> Any . isOne)) [0..100]
[0,1]
```

It's a bit longer than the `Applicative` solution, but I think it's a little easier to follow when you have more conditions to combine. Compare

```
getAny . (Any . isZero <> Any . isOne <> Any . isSquare <> Any . isPrime)
```

or

```
getAny . foldMap (Any .) [isZero, isOne, isSquare, isPrime]
```

and

```
liftA2 (||) (liftA2 (||) (liftA2 (||) isZero isOne) isSquare) isPrime
```

or

```
liftA2 (||) isZero $ liftA2 (||) isOne $ liftA2 (||) isSquare isPrime
```

Though to be honest, if I had lots of these to do, I'd be tempted to define `<||> = liftA2 (||)` and do

```
isZero <||> isOne <||> isSquare <||> isPrime
```